# Prisma delete() function returns "Argument where of type TodoWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument"

Tags: node.js, express, backend, prisma

I'm making a call to prisma.delete() function in order to delete a record from my database but I get this error:

```
Invalid `prisma.todo.delete()` invocation
------
Argument where of type TodoWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument. Available args are listed in green.
```

This is the `schema.prisma` file:

```
model Todo {
  Todo_ID          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  Title            String?   @db.VarChar(255)
  Body             String?   @db.Text
  Create_Time      DateTime? @db.DateTime(0)
  Last_Update_Time DateTime? @db.DateTime(0)
  Status           Int?      @default(0) @db.TinyInt
  InRecycleBin     Int?      @default(0) @db.TinyInt
  Username         String?
  Users            Users?    @relation(fields: [Username], references: [Username], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "Todo_ibfk_1")

  @@index([Username], map: "Username")
}

model Users {
  Username String @id @unique(map: "Username") @db.VarChar(255)
  Password String @db.VarChar(255)
  Todo     Todo[]
}
```

and this is the function I'm trying to execute:

```
export async function DeleteTodo(todo_Id: number): Promise<Todo | null> {
  try {
    const result = await prisma.todo.delete({
      where: {
        Todo_ID: todo_Id,
      }
    });
    if (typeof result !== null) return result;
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Can someone please help? I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong

I tried to use `deleteMany()` instead of `delete()` and it works like that, but the return type is different and I really don't understand why it doesn't work with `delete()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was to validate that todo_Id was not a null or undefined value.